# Multiple insert array POST values from foreach loop into mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2">First Name</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Last Name</th>
            <th  class="col-md-2">Present</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Absent</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php foreach($teacher_names as $name): ?>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-2"><input class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="f_name" value="<?php echo $name['first_name']; ?>"></td>
                <td class="col-md-2"><input class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="l_name" value="<?php echo $name['last_name']; ?>"></td>
                <td class="col-md-2"><input type="checkbox" name="present" value="Y"></td>
                <td class="col-md-2"><input type="checkbox" name="absent" value="N"></td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

I want to be able to access all values in my database which at the moment is 10. I want to get all the `$_POST` values and then insert them into the database but it seems i only get the one `POST` value in the `foreach` loop which is the last key value. An example of the php script is

```
public function teachers_attendance($first_name, $last_name, $present, $absent){                    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO teacher_attendance($first_name, $last_name, $present, $absent) 
            VALUES(:first_name, :last_name, :present, :absent)";

    $stmt = $this->_connection->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':first_name', $first_name, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':last_name', $last_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':present', $present, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':absent', $absent, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->Execute();


    $num_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($num_rows > 0){
        echo "Yes";
    }else{
        echo "No";
    }

}
```

I just would want to be able to access all the `POST` value and `checkbox` values into an array and then insert them all in the database. I would be grateful if i can have some solutions to this problem.

Comment: On first glance, I would say the `name` attributes on the form elements in your loop are the issue. The `name` attributes are what `$_POST` references, and in your looped HTML, they are all the same, which would cause one to overwrite the next and so on, leaving you with only the last set. Appending a value unique to each iteration of the loop to the `name` attribute on those fields may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since it didn't click with me the first time about un-matching keys when checkboxes are not selected, I've written up another method of accomplishing what you're after.

So your template should be as follows:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2">First Name</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Last Name</th>
            <th  class="col-md-2">Present</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Absent</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
    $i = 0;
    foreach($teacher_names as $name):
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-2"><input class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="f_name_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $name['first_name']; ?>" /></td>
            <td class="col-md-2"><input class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="l_name_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $name['last_name']; ?>" /></td>
            <td class="col-md-2"><input type="checkbox" name="present_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="Y" /></td>
            <td class="col-md-2"><input type="checkbox" name="absent_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="N" /></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $i++;
    endforeach;
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you start at 0, add 1 each time, and loop until numbered name fields are no longer found (at which point it is assumed there are no more entries)

```
<?php

// First row to check is 0, as per template
$i = 0;

// Loop while f_name_* and l_name_* are found (if not found, it is assumed there are no more rows)
while( isset( $_POST['f_name_'.$i] ) && isset( $_POST['l_name_'.$i] ) )
{
    // Get and set name variables (based on current row)
    $first_name = $_POST['f_name_'.$i];
    $last_name  = $_POST['l_name_'.$i];

    // Presence and absence are checkboxes with a Y value, so we'll set these to 'N' if not found
    $present    = ( isset( $_POST['present_'.$i] ) ? $_POST['present_'.$i] : 'N' );
    $absent     = ( isset( $_POST['absent_'.$i] )  ? $_POST['absent_'.$i]  : 'N' );

    // Call the teachers_attendance function
    teachers_attendance($first_name, $last_name, $present, $absent);

    // Increment the row to check
    $i++;
}

?>
```

Comment: since unchecked checkboxes are not sent, you will run into issues with `isset( $_POST['present'][$i]`/`isset( $_POST['absent'][$i]`, as you will have un-matching keys. Example, you have 10 `$_POST['f_name']`, with 5 present and 5 absent. `$_POST['present'][4]` and `$_POST['absent'][4]` is the max you will get, so you won't have a match for `$_POST['f_name'][9]`

Comment: Yes you are right Sean, how do you suggest i should go about it

Comment: @user3769234 I've altered my answer to include a solution that should take theissue Sean pointed out into account (thanks for pointing it out, Sean!)